# Chirality of buta-1,2-diene

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

My teacher says buta-1,2-diene is symmetric and hence optically inactive but I think it's the opposite, because allenes with an even number of double bonds are optically active because they have no plane of symmetry. Which answer is correct?

Answer (score 10):

Let's see if a picture can help.  Newman projections can be handy in analyzing the stereochemistry of allenes.  On the left is a Newman projection of methyl allene (buta-1,2-diene).  There is a sigma plane of symmetry that is perpendicular to the screen and contains the 3 allenic carbons plus the methyl group.  Any molecule with a plane of symmetry is achiral.  On the other hand, look at the Newman projection to the right, 1,3-dimethyallene (penta-2,3-diene).  There is no plane symmetry in this case, only a $\ce{C_2}$ axis.  Draw the mirror image of the pictured allene and you will find that it is not superimposable on its mirror image. 1,3-dimethylallene is a chiral molecule.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

2,3-butadiene is not a IUPAC name. It should be 1,2-butadiene. I think you are talking about 1,3-butadiene (natural rubber). In any case, neither of the molecules have a chiral center; therefore, no optical activity.

Comment: Buta-1,3-dien is not an Allene, so I think the OP is actually talking about Buta-1,2-dien.

Comment: Yes, exactly martin

Comment: OK, my mistake. But there is no chiral center since C1 has 2 hydrogens. 2,3-hexadiene would be chiral.

Comment: As is penta-2,3-diene (1,3-dimethylallene).

Comment: Also, natural rubber is comprised of isoprenes (i.e. isopentadienes), not butadienes.